# Maven : How to move a file during assembly

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

During assemby, I want include all files from a release directory into the root of my assembly.
If I do the following:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>${basedir}/</directory>
  <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>src/main/resources/release/**</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

Then all of the files get added to a folder named src/main/resources/release/ inside my release.
Is there a way to not include the folder path when including the fields?

I'm using the 2.3 version of the assembly plugin. If there is not a way to do this with the assembly plugin is there a way to do this with other plugins? (preferably without resorting to the ant plugin).

Comment: You know of the existence of bin, src and jar-with-dependencies descriptors? What would you like to achieve? src/main/resources is the default location for resources which will be packaged into the resulting jar artifact.

Comment: Yes, the default descriptor types aren't sufficient in this case. I'm build a release zip that will include a specific set of property files and scripts that differs from the properties that will be run during the build.

Comment: Have you tested to give only a single "*" in the include ? But this means only the files inside the folder src/main/resources/release/.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me unfortunately- the whole path is still included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do the configuration a little bit different like this:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>src/main/resources/release/</directory>
  <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>**</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```